# Accessing a legacy Shopware plugin from one written for Shopware 5.2

Tags: php, shopware

I'm developing a plugin for Shopware 5.2.
However, in my application, there are also legacy plugins from before the upgrade to version 5.2.

The documentation tells me to use a call like this in order to access another specific plugin from within my plugin:

```
$plugin = Shopware()->Container()->get('kernel')->getPlugins()['anotherPlugin'];
```

Unfortunately, this returns `null` with legacy plugins, as the method `getPlugins()` returns an array containing only the plugins written for version 5.2 (those residing in the `custom/plugins` folder).

How can I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the legacy Versions you can retrieve the plugins from the container:

```
Shopware()->Container()->get('plugins')->Backend()->NameOfYourPlugin();
```

or with `Frontend` if it is a frontend Plugin

or with `Core` if it is a Shopware Core Legacy Plugin.

I will suggest you to migrate to the new structure, because this will not be supported for long (if not already with the 5.3).

Comment: In our case, it was `Core()` instead of `Backend()`, but you put me on the right track! Thank you very much!